# Vector space of orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality

$S=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n|\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{n}=0\}$ where $\mathbf{n}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a fixed vector.

Is $S$ a vector space? If so, what is a basis for it?

In $\mathbb{R}^3$

$\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$

$\mathbf{n} = (n_1, n_2, n_3)$

$x_1n_1+x_2n_2+x_3n_3=0$

$x_1 = \dfrac{-x_2n_2-x_3n_3}{n_1}$

$(\dfrac{-x_2n_2-x_3n_3}{n_1}, x_2, x_3)$

$x_2(\dfrac{-n_2}{n1}, 1, 0) + x_3(\dfrac{-n_3}{n1}, 0, 1)$

So the basis would be $(\dfrac{-n_2}{n1}, 1, 0)$ and $(\dfrac{-n_3}{n1}, 0, 1)$

Does this mean that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the basis vectors are

$(\dfrac{-n_2}{n1}, 1, 0, 0...)$ , $(\dfrac{-n_3}{n1}, 0, 1, 0...)$, $(\dfrac{-n_4}{n1}, 0, 0, 1...)$, ...

Comment: Do not post what is clearly homework with absolutely zero effort.

Comment: I believe it to be a vector space, but I have no idea how to find the basis for this. I've tried finding information on Google but I can't find anything for this specific scenario

Comment: Haven’t you learned how to write the general solution of a system of linear equations?

Comment: I’m unsure of how to approach it in R^n. On a side note, why do you insist on insulting me for asking for help instead of choosing to just explain this concept to me? I’m clearly struggling to understand this and your condescending insults are not helping.

Comment: Because you're not giving *any* indication of what you've been taught, where this question is arising, and what tools you have to approach it. Nor can we guess *what* you are struggling to understand. This is why we want to see effort. We obviously are not going to write out a whole chapter of a textbook here.

Comment: If this was given in R^3, for example, I know how to find a basis for the space. However, with R^n, I don’t know how to even begin finding a basis

Comment: OK, edit your post to show your work to do it in $\Bbb R^3$ and $\Bbb R^4$. In general, you're going to have to generalize and use some $\dots$ in your answers.

Comment: If you know how to solve it in $\Bbb R^3$, then you should know how to solve it in $\Bbb R^n$. The process is exactly the same, except you have more variables, and need to take more steps. But the problem does not ask about "finding a basis", so why are you trying to do so? That is a lot of work for nothing to be gained, Just check to see if the vectors in this set satisfy all the conditions to be a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. If you do not know what those conditions are, then you need to crack open your textbook and start reading, because you should have learned them by now.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The question says, "If so, what is a basis for it?"

Comment: Okay - I had indeed overlooked that. However, the rest is the same as in $\Bbb R^3$. Have you confirmed it is a vector space? If so, choose a vector not parallel to $\bf n$, and subtract its projection on $\bf n$ from it to get a vector in $S$. Then choose a vector that is linearly dependent from both vectors, and subtract out its projection on $\bf n$ to find another vector in $S$. Keep going until you cannot find another linearly independent vector.

Comment: I spoke to my professor and he said that asking us to find a basis was a mistake. He simply wanted us to determine whether or not it was a vector space. If it seemed like I was out my depth, this is probably why.

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited my original post

Comment: Yes, that’s perfect, provided $n_1\ne 0$. If $n_1=0$, then take the first nonzero entry of $n$ and use that as your pivot.

Comment: Thank you for helping me!